# Basic function and if statement not working in jQuery

Tags: jquery, if-statement

Here's my code:

```
<button id="addSubject" type="button">+</button> 
    <script>                            
        $('#addSubject').click(function() 
        {
                function optionExists(mySelect, val) 
                {
                    return $("#"+mySelect+" option").filter(function() {
                        return this.value === val;
                    }).length !== 0;
                }

                if (optionExists($('#subjectCategories'), $('#fieldNewSubject').val()))
                {
                    $('#subjectCategories').append("<option value=\"" + $('#fieldNewSubject').val() + "\">" + $('#fieldNewSubject').val() + "</option>");
                    $('#fieldNewSubject').val("");
            });  
    </script>
```

Here's my quetion: Why won't it work? Nothing happens when I click on the button!
I did put this in the header:

```
<script src="js/jquery.ui.button.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: on a first glance: `$('#subjectCategories')` will be an object, yet you're using it as a string `$("#"+mySelect+" option")`.

Comment: I didn't catch that. I meant by $("#"+mySelect+" option") that I want mySelect to be replaced with the name of the object given in parameter of the function...

Comment: try: `mySelect.find('option')` instead

Comment: Your scripts are in the wrong order, you have to load jquery before loading jquery-ui.

Comment: I think the sense of your test is backwards. You should add the option if it _doesn't_ exist, not if it _does_.

Comment: Didn't solve the problem, but the answer below just did. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I guessed your intention correctly, this should do the same:

```
$('#addSubject').click(function () {
  var
    val = $('#fieldNewSubject').val(),
    $select = $('#subjectCategories');

  if ($select.find('option[value="' + val + '"]').length === 0) {
    $('<option>', {
      value: val,
      text: val
    }).appendTo($select);
  }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/usadoq/1/